Authorization of database model field using nestjs @nextjs/typeorm @nestjs/graphql
I'm using nestjs with @nestjs/typeorm and @nestjs/graphql beside some REST API in my backend.
And for authorization, I'm using a token that will be sent to the backend with each request header that will be validated every time and will be used to fetch user permissions.
I can modify the execution context and inject user permissions through the context function of the Graphqlmodule.

@Injectable()
export class gqconf implements GqlOptionsFactory {
   
    createGqlOptions(): ApolloDriverConfig {
        return {
            
            context: async ({req, res}) => {
                let ctx: CustomContext = {
                    req,
                    res,
                    permissions: [],
                }

                return (ctx);
            },

        }

    }

}


But I can not modify the original (non-GraphQL) execution context to inject user permissions
Q1. Is there a way to inject user permissions in both the REST execution context and GraphQL execution context? or should I inject permissions in every context separately?
Q2. How to inject permissions in the original REST context?
Also, I want to limit access to a field of typeorm model according to user permissions.
This database model will be used as an object type through the @ObjectType decorator, and each desired field to be exposed will use the @Field decorator.
I cannot use a custom decorator over desired field as it throws error.
Q3.I want a way to access the execution context within the database model.
@ObjectType()
@Entity({name: 'appointment', database: 'name'})
export class Appointment extends BaseEntity {

    @Field(() => String)
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @Field(() => GraphQLISODateTime)
    @Column({name: "date", type: "datetime"})
    date: string;

    @CHECK_USER_PERMISSION(IF AUTHORIZED => REVEAL FIELD VALUE, IF NOT RETURN NULL) <====
    @Field(() => Int)
    @Column({name: 'fees', type: "int"})
    fees: number;

    @Field(() => String, {nullable: true})
    @Column({name: 'notes', type: "longtext"})
    notes: string;

}

THANKS IN ADVANCE
